# Flutter: Why setState(( ) { }) set data again and again

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I use `setState(() {})` for assigning a value to a variable. But it's printing again and again. Why does it react like this? And how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  String _message;
  String _appLink;
  Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    db.collection('share').document('0').get().then((value) {
      var message = value.data['message'];
      print(message);
      var appLink = value.data['appLink'];
      setState(() {
        _message = message;
        _appLink = appLink;
      });
    });
    return Container(
      child: Text('$_message $_appLink'),
    );
  }
}
```

> Here is my Output:

Here `_appLink` value is `www.facebook.com`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `setState` is to tell the framework that a variable in the state has changed and the widget needs to be rebuilt to reflect that change. So calling `setState` calls the `build` function again, which in your case recalls your `Future`, which calls `setState` again, which triggers `build` and so on.

To fix this you should call the `Future` in `initState`, and use a `FutureBuilder` to display the data when it's ready.

Example:

```
class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
  Future databaseFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    databaseFuture = db.collection('share').document('0').get()
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: databaseFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        var message = snapshot.data.data['message'];
        print(message);
        var appLink = snapshot.data.data['appLink'];
        return Text('$message $appLink');
      }
    ),
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem. I get this error - `Another exception was thrown: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`

Comment: Please show where this assertion is thrown. It's likely unrelated to this question. If so you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. I asked another question and solved this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62874312/12902996