# Flutter Firestore Snapshot Documents loop doesnot stop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

So i have made a screen which has a future builder and takes getJobs() as the future. The problem is that the future builder gets null data because the loop of snapshot documents doesnot stop. Here is the Code:

```
Future<List<Job>> getJobs() async {
    var fbuser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
//    print('got user');
    var currentUser =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(fbuser.uid).get();
    setState(() {
      seeker = currentUser.data['seeker'];
//      print('seeker value = $seeker');
    });
    var snapshots = await Firestore.instance.collection('jobs').getDocuments();
    var snapshotDocuments = snapshots.documents;
    List<Job> jobs = [];
//    print('got Jobs');
    for (var docs in snapshotDocuments) {
      var job = Job(
        uid: docs.data['uid'],
        salaryTo: docs.data['salTo'],
        salaryFrom: docs.data['salFrom'],
        exp: docs.data['exp'],
        loc: docs.data['loc'],
        title: docs.data['title'],
        desc: docs.data['desc'],
        skill: docs.data['skill'],
        companyName: docs.data['companyName'],
      );
      print(job);
      jobs.add(job);
    }

    print('returning $jobs');
    return jobs;
  }
```

And here is the build method

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getJobs(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
//          print(snapshot.hasData);
          if (snapshot.data == null)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          else
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Center(child: Text('GOT DATA'),);
                });
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
          visible: seeker ? false : true,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add_box),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Thanks for your help !!

EDIT
Ok, I have found that error is in this block

```
var job = Job(
        uid: snapshotDocuments[i].data['uid'],
        salaryTo: snapshotDocuments[i].data['salTo'],
        salaryFrom: snapshotDocuments[i].data['salFrom'],
        exp: snapshotDocuments[i].data['exp'],
        loc: snapshotDocuments[i].data['loc'],
        title: snapshotDocuments[i].data['title'],
        desc: snapshotDocuments[i].data['desc'],
        skill: snapshotDocuments[i].data['skill'],
        companyName: snapshotDocuments[i].data['companyName'],
      );
```

If I remove the job class instance creation the data loop ends, and I dont know why is that happening.

Comment: i suppose the `setState()` inside the `getJobs()` is the issue. It asks flutter to redraw the widget thus calling itself recursively.

Comment: No still same issue

Comment: so removing the `setState()` still gives you the loading circle and nothing else?

Comment: I have updated the question, kindly give it a look and tell me

Comment: Seems like there is an exception somewhere. Try adding a check for `snapshot.hasError` in the `FutureBuilder` that will help find the exception. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874312/flutter-failed-assertion-boolean-expression-must-not-be-null/62875106#62875106

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I was assigning a string to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` will keep returing `snapshot.data` as `null` if there is an exception due to any reason e.g. server issues, internet not available or there is some exception generating from your own code.

So, it's always advisable to have 3 cases in the `FutureBuilder`.

1. Valid data arrived
2. Data is loading
3. Error during data load

Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874312/flutter-failed-assertion-boolean-expression-must-not-be-null/62875106#62875106)

Comment: The problem was in the Job section. snapshot was returning a string and I was storing it in an int.